# Interceptor doesn't add header to get request

Tags: angular, http-headers, interceptor

I made this interceptor:

```js
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Clone the request to add the new header
        if (req.url.includes('GetFriend')){
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Accept'       : 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`
                }
        });

        return next.handle(req);
    }

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

This provider:

```js
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AddHeaderInterceptor, multi: true },
],
```

And that's the get request, that needs the header:

```js
this.http.get('http://localhost:52575/api/account/GetFriends').subscribe((res: FriendsList)=>{
    this.friends = res;
});
```

I looked at Fiddler, what packages I send to server, there aren't any information about added headers and server send me this error "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized":

Comment: Are you sure the interceptor is intercepted?

Comment: Yeah same question as Andrei, throw a breakpoint into your interceptor or a console log or something and let us know if it is hit when making the request.